# Date math using segments

Tags: solspace, date, solspace-calendar, date-format, mx-calculator

I need to take `{segment_n}` where the segment is either a Month, Day, or Year value and add values to it. For example, I need to be able to add values like so:

```
{embed="calendar/landing" month_start="{segment_2}" month_end="{segment_2} +1 month"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There wasn't really a question here, but... :)

If you're using Solspace Calendar, which I assume you are since you've tagged it as such, you don't have to do this calculation, it's already built into the addon. For instance, you could do this:

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="{year}-{segment_2}-first" date_range_end="+1 month"}
```

Comment: Hehe, no problem, glad you figured it out. :)